# Wpf - Show Textbox ToolTip

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<TextBox Name="txtInput">
<TextBox.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Name="TestToolTip">
        This a test message
    </ToolTip>
</TextBox.ToolTip>
```

```
private void btnClick_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtInput.Focus();
    ToolTipTest.IsVisible = true;
}
```

When the button is clicked the tooltip is shown on the button, I want to simulate putting mouse pointer on the textbox, the toolbox to be shown for the textbox

Comment: Why would you simulate anything ? With the code you posted, the tooltip should appear when you put the mouse over the TextBox...

Comment: I want to put BL into Click handler, for example - if the textbox is empty, focus it and tooltip appears "Please fill it".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should be using the standard validation for something like what you are doing.  From your comment above I can tell that's what you are doing and you should know that WPF has a really good builtin system for doing exactly what you want without doing it so imperatively (and very reusable).

Here's an example of a style you can apply to, say, all textboxes when the value the are bound to doesn't validate (using IDataErrorInfo).

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
           <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" IsOpen="true" />
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You might also consider a more standard UI that utilizes the adorner layer to put a validation failure indicator next to the control that failed validation.  Here's a sample on that:

http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/03/handling-error-in-wpf-idataerrorinfo.html

Good luck.